# Qt Multimedia: Library 'gstreamer' is not defined

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, ubuntu-16.04, gstreamer

I have problem building QtMultimedia with GStreamer:

```
user@user-VirtualBox:~/sources/qt/build$ /usr/local/Qt-5.12.1/bin/qmake -r GST_VERSION=1.0 ../qt-everywhere-src-5.12.1/qtmultimedia/qtmultimedia.pro 
Info: creating stash file /home/user/sources/qt/build/.qmake.stash
Info: creating cache file /home/user/sources/qt/build/.qmake.cache

Running configuration tests...
Checking for ALSA... no
Checking for GStreamer 1.0... yes
Checking for GStreamer App 1.0... yes
Checking for GStreamer encoding-profile.h... yes
Checking for GStreamer Photography 1.0... no
Checking for Video for Linux... yes
Checking for OpenAL... no
Checking for PulseAudio >= 0.9.10... no
Checking for libresourceqt5... no
Done running configuration tests.

Configure summary:

Qt Multimedia:
  ALSA ................................... no
  GStreamer 1.0 .......................... yes
  GStreamer 0.10 ......................... no
  Video for Linux ........................ yes
  OpenAL ................................. no
  PulseAudio ............................. no
  Resource Policy (libresourceqt5) ....... no
  Windows Audio Services ................. no
  DirectShow ............................. no
  Windows Media Foundation ............... no

Qt is now configured for building. Just run 'make'.
Once everything is built, you must run 'make install'.
Qt will be installed into '/usr/local/Qt-5.12.1'.

Prior to reconfiguration, make sure you remove any leftovers from
the previous build.

Reading /home/user/sources/qt/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.1/qtmultimedia/src/src.pro [/home/user/sources/qt/build/src]
 Reading /home/user/sources/qt/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.1/qtmultimedia/src/multimedia/multimedia.pro [/home/user/sources/qt/build/src/multimedia]
 Reading /home/user/sources/qt/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.1/qtmultimedia/src/qtmultimediaquicktools/qtmultimediaquicktools.pro [/home/user/sources/qt/build/src/qtmultimediaquicktools]
 Reading /home/user/sources/qt/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.1/qtmultimedia/src/imports/imports.pro [/home/user/sources/qt/build/src/imports]
  Reading /home/user/sources/qt/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.1/qtmultimedia/src/imports/multimedia/multimedia.pro [/home/user/sources/qt/build/src/imports/multimedia]
 Reading /home/user/sources/qt/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.1/qtmultimedia/src/multimediawidgets/multimediawidgets.pro [/home/user/sources/qt/build/src/multimediawidgets]
 Reading /home/user/sources/qt/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.1/qtmultimedia/src/gsttools/gsttools.pro [/home/user/sources/qt/build/src/gsttools]
Project ERROR: Library 'gstreamer' is not defined.
```

I believe that I've installed all required GStreamer components, but it looks like the GStreamer library was't found. Any ideas?

OS: **Ubuntu 16.04**
Installed **GStreamer** related packages:

gir1.2-gst-plugins-bad-1.0/xenial-updates,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2 i386 [installed]

gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-0.10/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 0.10.36-2ubuntu0.1 i386 [installed]

gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2 i386 [installed]

gir1.2-gstreamer-0.10/xenial,now 0.10.36-1.5ubuntu1 i386 [installed,automatic]

gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0/xenial-updates,now 1.8.3-1~ubuntu0.1 i386 [installed]

gstreamer-qapt/xenial-updates,now 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.2 i386 [installed,automatic]

gstreamer0.10-alsa/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 0.10.36-2ubuntu0.1 i386 [installed]

gstreamer0.10-doc/xenial,now 0.10.36-1.5ubuntu1 all [installed]

gstreamer0.10-gconf/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 0.10.31-3+nmu4ubuntu2.16.04.3 i386 [installed]

gstreamer0.10-gnomevfs/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 0.10.36-2ubuntu0.1 i386 [installed]

gstreamer0.10-nice/xenial,now 0.1.13-0ubuntu2 i386 [installed]

gstreamer0.10-plugins-base/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 0.10.36-2ubuntu0.1 i386 [installed]

gstreamer0.10-plugins-base-apps/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 0.10.36-2ubuntu0.1 i386 [installed]

gstreamer0.10-plugins-base-dbg/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 0.10.36-2ubuntu0.1 i386 [installed]

gstreamer0.10-plugins-base-doc/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 0.10.36-2ubuntu0.1 all [installed]

gstreamer0.10-plugins-good/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 0.10.31-3+nmu4ubuntu2.16.04.3 i386 [installed]

gstreamer0.10-plugins-good-dbg/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 0.10.31-3+nmu4ubuntu2.16.04.3 i386 [installed]

gstreamer0.10-plugins-good-doc/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 0.10.31-3+nmu4ubuntu2.16.04.3 all [installed]

gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 0.10.31-3+nmu4ubuntu2.16.04.3 i386 [installed]

gstreamer0.10-qapt/xenial-updates,now 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.2 all [installed]

gstreamer0.10-tools/xenial,now 0.10.36-1.5ubuntu1 i386 [installed]

gstreamer0.10-x/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 0.10.36-2ubuntu0.1 i386 [installed]

gstreamer1.0-alsa/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2 i386 [installed]

gstreamer1.0-clutter/xenial,now 2.0.18-1 i386 [installed]

gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0/xenial,now 3.0.18-1 i386 [installed]

gstreamer1.0-crystalhd/xenial,now 1:0.0~git20110715.fdd2f19-11build1 i386 [installed]

gstreamer1.0-doc/xenial-updates,now 1.8.3-1~ubuntu0.1 all [installed]

gstreamer1.0-dvswitch/xenial,now 0.1.1-1 i386 [installed]

gstreamer1.0-espeak/xenial,now 0.4.0-1 i386 [installed]

gstreamer1.0-fluendo-mp3/xenial,now 0.10.32.debian-1 i386 [installed]

gstreamer1.0-hybris/xenial-updates,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2 i386 [installed]

gstreamer1.0-libav/xenial-updates,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2 i386 [installed]

gstreamer1.0-libav-dbg/xenial-updates,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2 i386 [installed]

gstreamer1.0-nice/xenial,now 0.1.13-0ubuntu2 i386 [installed]

gstreamer1.0-packagekit/xenial-updates,now 0.8.17-4ubuntu6~gcc5.4ubuntu1.4 i386 [installed]

gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad/xenial-updates,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2 i386 [installed]

gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-dbg/xenial-updates,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2 i386 [installed]

gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-doc/xenial-updates,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2 all [installed]

gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-faad/xenial-updates,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2 i386 [installed]

gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-videoparsers/xenial-updates,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2 i386 [installed]

gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2 i386 [installed]

gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2 i386 [installed]

gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-dbg/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2 i386 [installed]

gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-doc/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2 all [installed]

gstreamer1.0-plugins-good/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.4 i386 [installed]

gstreamer1.0-plugins-good-dbg/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.4 i386 [installed]

gstreamer1.0-plugins-good-doc/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.4 all [installed]

gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly/xenial-updates,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.1 i386 [installed]

gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly-amr/xenial-updates,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.1 i386 [installed]

gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly-dbg/xenial-updates,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.1 i386 [installed]

gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly-doc/xenial-updates,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.1 all [installed]

gstreamer1.0-pocketsphinx/xenial,now 0.8.0+real5prealpha-1ubuntu2 i386 [installed]

gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.4 i386 [installed]

gstreamer1.0-tools/xenial-updates,now 1.8.3-1~ubuntu0.1 i386 [installed]

gstreamer1.0-vaapi/xenial-updates,now 1.8.3-1~ubuntu0.1 i386 [installed]

gstreamer1.0-vaapi-doc/xenial-updates,now 1.8.3-1~ubuntu0.1 all [installed]

gstreamer1.0-x/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2 i386 [installed]

libclutter-gst-3.0-0/xenial,now 3.0.18-1 i386 [installed]

libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0/xenial-updates,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2 i386 [installed,automatic]

libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 0.10.36-2ubuntu0.1 i386 [installed,automatic]

libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2 i386 [installed]

libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2 i386 [installed]

libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.4 i386 [installed]

libgstreamer0.10-0/xenial,now 0.10.36-1.5ubuntu1 i386 [installed,automatic]

libgstreamer0.10-dev/xenial,now 0.10.36-1.5ubuntu1 i386 [installed,automatic]

libgstreamer1.0-0/xenial-updates,now 1.8.3-1~ubuntu0.1 i386 [installed]

libgstreamer1.0-0-dbg/xenial-updates,now 1.8.3-1~ubuntu0.1 i386 [installed]

libgstreamer1.0-dev/xenial-updates,now 1.8.3-1~ubuntu0.1 i386 [installed]

libqt5gstreamer-1.0-0/xenial,now 1.2.0-3 i386 [installed]

libqtgstreamer-1.0-0/xenial,now 1.2.0-3 i386 [installed]

libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial6 i386 [installed]

Comment: How have you installed GStreamer? What is your OS?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that crucial informations.